# Deploy meteor server using development mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm currently trying to deploy a Meteor server from scratch using the command `meteor build`, there is no big issue but a question that may be very dumb.

In development environment, a mongodb instance is automatically started when I start my Meteor server with `meteor`. My question is, why can't I use this feature in production ?

The bundle created with `meteor build` contains "only" the node server and the client application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the environment variable like:

```
export PORT=3000;
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/my-app
```

Then you can run the main.js file using node.

```
node main.js
```

> Note: When you build a meteor app. It converts the meteor app into a
>   simple node app. As node doest not provide any MongoDB instance, So
>   you have to run a separate MongoDB server to perform DB operation.

Comment: Thanks, but it don't work, I get an error `MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect` because I suppose there is no running Mongodb instance. Moreover, I believed `3001` was the default port used by Meteor for mongodb ?

Comment: You need to run the mongo server on your local machine.

Comment: Install the MongoDB server. Then start the server and it will work.

Comment: Yeah...I know, but I think you misunderstood my question. I just want to know why Meteor provides an built-in mongodb instance in development but not in production ?

Comment: Okay, I missed this note in Meteor documentation. Thank you for your help.